# Python 2.7 urllib2 raising urllib2.HTTPError 301 when hitting redirect with xml content

Tags: python, html, xml, urllib2, http-status-code-301

I'm using urllib2 to request a particular S3 bucket at `hxxp://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket`.  Amazon sends back an HTTP code of 301 along with some XML data (the redirect being to `hxxp://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/`).  Instead of following the redirect, python raises `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 301: Moved Permanently`.

According to the official Python docs at [HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html), "the default handlers handle redirects (codes in the 300 range)".

Is python handling this incorrectly (presumably because of the unexpected XML in the response), or am I doing something wrong?  I've watched in Wireshark and the response comes back exactly the same to python's request as it does to me using a web client.  In debugging, I don't see the XML being captured anywhere in the response object.

Thanks for any guidance.

Edit: Sorry for not posting the code initially.  It's nothing special, literally just this -

```
import urllib2, httplib

request = urllib2.Request(site)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Where's the code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, added now.  I'm not using any special handlers or doing much.

Comment: @KayBalearica You could consider switching to the `requests` module.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks for the suggestion.  It handles it correctly for me.  Does the urllib2 behavior seem like a bug to you?

Comment: @KayBalearica Not sure, maybe python3's urllib module would have handled this. I just feel urllib2 sucks and shouldn't be used :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Lol, fair enough!

Comment: Would need to find a globally accessible bucket for this can be repeated. So far: none.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The one I was testing with wasn't globally accessible - it would give an access denied once it redirected.  However, for security reasons, I don't want to disclose it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using the `requests` library. `requests` handle redirection by default : http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

```
import requests

response = requests.get(site)
print(response.content)
```

I don't get the problem with urllib2, I tried to look into the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html but it doesn't look intuitive.

It seems that in Python3, they refactored it to make it less a burden to use, but I am still convinced that `requests` is the way to go.

> Note The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in
>   Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like that's what I'll end up doing.  I'm still interested to know if that's expected urllib2 behavior, though.