# HTTPError: Moved Permanently raised by urllib2.urlopen()

Tags: python, python-2.7, request

I am trying to send a patch request a database using urllib and urllib2 library in python 2.7 (as I cannot use requests library cause it does not work in this server and nobody has found the solution for that, so please do not  suggest requests because that path is already closed).

The code look like this:

```
data={"name":"whatever name"}
data=urllib.urlencode(data,'utf-8')#Encoding the dictionary of the data to make the request
req=urllib2.Request(url=next_url,headers={"Authorization": auth_header,"Content-Type": "application/json"})#Creating a request object of urllib library
req.add_data=data
req.get_method = lambda: 'PATCH'
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

If don't assign both  `req.get_method=lambda: 'PATCH'` , `req.add_data=data` the request class automatically sends a get request which has a 200 response, so I guess it does not have to do with the authorization and credentials. Using python 3 and urllib.request library works as well, so the server accept for sure PATCH requests.

I hope that anybody can find the solution... I cannot picture why this' happening.

Update SOLVED: I find the problem, to be related with the url I was making the request.

Answer (score 1):

The "Moved Permanently" error would indicate that the server responded with a HTTP 301 error, meaning that the URL you are requesting has been moved to another URL (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301).

I would suggest to take a network traffic capture with tools like tcpdump or wireshark, to check the HTTP conversation and confirm . If the server is actually replying with a 301 and this is not urllib raising a wrong error code, the server response should include a "Location" header with another URL, and you should try this one instead.

Note that [urllib has problems when dealing with redirects.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269852/python-2-7-urllib2-raising-urllib2-httperror-301-when-hitting-redirect-with-xml), so you might want to reconsider trying to make the "requests" module work instead.